# ForeignKey column on grid

Tags: c#, grid, foreign-keys, kendo-ui

I am trying to add a ForeignKey column to a grid in Kendo UI with C#, with a SQL Server database which is connected via Linq-to-Sql. I don't find the way to populate the combobox/dropdownlist..

I have the controller (the model is automatically created when I create the Linq-to-sql file).. but I don't find the way to populate the combobox.

Here is the code:

```
c.ForeignKey(p => p.MerchantID, (IEnumerable)ViewData["Merchants"], "MerchantID", "Name").Title("Merchant").Width(150);
```

Comment: The combo box should be populated by `ViewData["Merchants"]` in your code snippet; have you double-checked that it contains valid data (with `MerchantID` and `Name` properties)?

Comment: Hi @Tomi Juniila, where should I check that? I have the `viewData["Merchants"]` in the controller, and when I pass it to a grid it populates without problem.. :/

Comment: The simplest way to check that is to add a breakpoint on the `return View(...)` line and check the contents of `ViewData["Merchants"]` in the debugger (or to dump it in the HTML somewhere, for example as comments).

Comment: But, I'm not really sure I've understood the structure of your view correctly. Usually, you'd pass the data for the grid itself in the first parameter of the `View()` function (i.e. you'd use a strongly-typed view); my understanding was this was a list of Stores, and then you'd have a second list of Merchants in `ViewData["Merchants"]` that you then pass as the list data in the ForeignKey column. Your comment to @Jaimin doesn't include a model in the `View()` call; how does your view get the data for the grid? (I suggest you edit the question to show a bit more context.)

Comment: Thanks again @Tommi Junnila.. This is what I have done: I have created the model through a Linq-to-Sql class, which created the models (Merchants, Stores, etc).. then I create a controller where I define the Actions in order to get, update, add or delete the data.. So I thought I could use the same Action `public ActionResult Merchants()` to fill the combobox/dropdownlist, and only set the dataTextField and the dataValueField... this is my combobox:

Comment: `<%: Html.Kendo().DropDownList() 
           .Name("comboMerchants")
           .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 250px"})
           .DataTextField("Name")
           .DataValueField("ID")
           //.BindTo((IEnumerable<PaysmardService.Models.Merchants>)ViewData["Merchants"])
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Merchants", "Home")))
    %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*********************  View  ***************************************/ 
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categoryList"], "CategoryID", "Category").Title("Organization Size").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fontbold" }).Width(170)

//*****************  Controller *************************//
 List<ManageModel> lookup = vendorTask.GetVendorCategory().Select(p => new ManageVendorModel { CategoryID = p.OrganizationSizeID, Category = p.OrganizationSizeName }).ToList<ManageModel>();
            lookup.Insert(0, (new ManageModel { CategoryID = 0, Category = " No Organization Size" }));
            ViewData["categoryList"] = lookup;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Jaimin! but this does not solve my problem :( In the Controller I have the ActionResult like this.   

`public ActionResult Merchants()
        {
            var merchants = new PaysmardService.Models.DCMerchantDataContext().Merchants;
            ViewData["Merchants"] = merchants;
            return View();
        }`

And it works perfect to populate a grid.

I have this two tables: Merchants and Stores..
the relationship is: Merchant -< Stores
So I want to show a dropdownlist/combobox on the grid with the list of Merchants on the Stores grid.